# How to add specific axes to matplotlib subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to make a matrix plot with matplotlib.

The individual plots are made with a specific module `windrose` which subclasses `PolarAxes`. However there does not seem to be any projection defined in the module to be called as subplot kwargs. The standard `polar` projection does not work since some of the subclass arguments are missing.

I have tested several approaches without success (even with seaborn map considering this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25702476/3416205). Hereunder is the closest I have tried. Is there any way to do what I want without properly creating a new matplotlib projection associated with the specific `WindroseAxes`?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from windrose import WindroseAxes

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AntoineGautier/Data/master/tmp.csv')
fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 2)

def wind_plot(x, y, title=None, axes=None, fig=None):
    ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
    ax.set_position(axes.get_position(fig))
    ax.bar(x, y, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white', bins=[0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10])
    ax.set_title(title)

for (id_s, s) in enumerate(pd.unique(df.saison)):
    for (id_jn, jn) in enumerate(pd.unique(df.jn)):
        tmp = df.query('saison==@s & jn==@jn')
        _ = plt.subplot(gs[id_s, id_jn], polar=True)
        wind_plot(tmp.wd, tmp.ws, title=s + ' - ' + jn, axes=_, fig=fig)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github page from the `windrose` module actually provides an example of subplots: https://github.com/scls19fr/windrose/blob/master/samples/example_subplots.py.

The following works.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from windrose import WindroseAxes

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AntoineGautier/Data/master/tmp.csv')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 4)
gp = gs.get_grid_positions(fig)  # [bottom, top, left, right]

def wind_plot(x, y, title, fig, rect):
    ax = WindroseAxes(fig, rect)
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    ax.bar(x, y, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white', bins=[0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10])
    ax.set_title(title, position=(0.5, 1.1))

for (id_s, s) in enumerate(pd.unique(df.saison)):
    for (id_jn, jn) in enumerate(pd.unique(df.jn)):
        tmp = df.query('saison==@s & jn==@jn')
        rect = [gp[2][id_s], gp[0][id_jn],
                gp[3][id_s]-gp[2][id_s],
                gp[1][id_jn]-gp[0][id_jn]]  # [left, bottom, width, height]
        wind_plot(tmp.wd, tmp.ws, s + ' | ' + jn, fig, rect)

plt.show()
```