# subplots in windrose diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib, windrose, rose-plot

I am very beginner to python. By following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733194/subplot-of-windrose-in-matplotlib) example I tried to make windrose subplots like:

[image]

but I am getting plots in this way:

[image]

```
The code that I tried is: 
ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
wd = np.random.random(500) * 360

fig=plt.figure()
rect=[0,0.5,0.4,0.4] 
wa=WindroseAxes(fig, rect)
fig.add_axes(wa)
wa.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')

fig1=plt.figure()
rect1=[0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4]
wa1=WindroseAxes(fig1, rect1)
fig1.add_axes(wa1)
wa1.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')

plt.show()
```

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: So your problem is that the subplots are vertically stacked instead of horizontal? You need to change your `rect` coords to fix that.

Comment: @BenT Exactly I want subplots in horizontal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your subplots to be horizontal you need to switch the numbers on your figure axis creation. When specifying your axis `rect = [lowerleft_x,lowerleft_y,width,height]`

Also note that you don't need to create a new figure when doing this.

```
ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
wd = np.random.random(500) * 360

fig=plt.figure()
rect=[0.5,0,0.4,0.4] 
wa=WindroseAxes(fig, rect)
fig.add_axes(wa)
wa.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')

rect1=[0.1, 0, 0.4, 0.4]
wa1=WindroseAxes(fig, rect1)
fig.add_axes(wa1)
wa1.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified by creating the subplots in the standard matplotlib way, but setting the projection to `'windrose'`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import windrose
import numpy as np

ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
wd = np.random.random(500) * 360

fig, (wa0, wa1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(9, 5),
                               subplot_kw={'projection': 'windrose'})

wa0.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
wa1.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: windrose inside subplots]