# How to plot two windrose-diagrams side by side

Tags: python, pandas, plot, windrose

I want to plot two windrose functions in python side by side, but I don't know how. I am using Panda and the windrose libary.

This is the Code I use to plot the two windroses:

```py
from windrose import WindroseAxes
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(dp['DD'], dp['FFAM'], normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor="white")
ax.set_legend();
ax.set_title('Patscherkofel')
ax2 = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax2.bar(dv['DD'],dv['FFAM'], normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor="white")
ax2.set_legend();
ax2.set_title('Valluga')
```

I already googled some methods, but it didn't work. (`subplot` and `subfig`). I also asked ChatGPT but the function just raised an error, and trying to get rid off the error just made the function useless. I think, that maybe the round style of the windrose is the problem and the functions I used, didn't fit it into a rectangle.

Comment: Try using `matplotlib` as well, following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733194/subplot-of-windrose-in-matplotlib).